# negative Delta y in derivatives.

Tags: derivatives

I'm first year in high school in Russia so please understand for noobyness and possible miss-formats.

From derivative definition we have: 
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}(\Delta y) / (\Delta x)
$$ 
Delta y is *f(x) - f(x0)*  which can be as a negative value depending on whether derivative is increasing, decr. or zero. but Delta usually means that we take difference between something. should we take an absolute value here? if don't, I get the derivatives. if do I ain't get it...

Thanks. I've tried to google this q I do promise.

Comment: What does "take a module here" mean?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom perhaps check the modulus/absolute value.

Comment: like |-2| = 2. directly from russian translated as module.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake "Modulus", "magnitude" and "absolute value" are the English terms

Comment: thank you! I will remember.

Comment: abs() like in programming. i get it :)

Comment: it is just a theoretical question. I mean I can definitely find this in books but I don't have time right now and I am obsessed with this question.

Comment: I am not certain I have well understood your question, but if you take the absolute value on $\Delta x$ **and** $\Delta y$, you will get the absolute value of the derivative... But if you take it only on $\Delta y$ the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I mean Delta y can be positive this is obvious. but can it be negative as Delta y is f(x)-f(x0) and if derivative is decreasing f(x)-f(x0) will be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said, we have $\Delta y = f(x) - f(x_0)$.  We then have $\Delta x = x-x_0$.  So, $\Delta x < 0$ when $x < x_0$, and $\Delta x > 0$ when $x > x_0$. No absolute values to take here.

The more common presentation of this limit is its full form
$$
f'(x_0) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)}{\Delta x}
$$
It is sometimes helpful to note that this is the same thing as writing
$$
f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}
$$
though in practice, the first version makes computation easier.

Comment: so Delta y should simply be replaced and Delta means not an absolute difference? Thank you!

Comment: That's right. It's a "signed" difference.